# How to test a contract's ability to receive an ERC721 token?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm testing my contract in Truffle. I enabled the contract to receive ERC721 tokens:

```
function onERC721Received(address, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes calldata) external override returns(bytes4) {
    nftContract = ERC721(msg.sender);
    tokenId = _tokenId;
    tokenAdded = true;

    return 0x150b7a02;
}
```

Is there a way to simulate a token being sent to this contract using Mocha and Chai?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of EVM (for example in a JS test), there's no way to check a return value of a transaction. Only its status (succeeded/reverted), emitted events (in your case non) and few other metadata. And you can also check return value of a call, as in the `assert.equal` statements.

```
contract('MyContract', () => {
    it('receives a token', async () => {
        const tx = await myContract.onERC721Received(
            '0x123',      // address
            '0x456',      // address _from
            1,            // uint256 _tokenId
            [0x01, 0x02]  // bytes calldata
        );

        assert.equal(tx.receipt.status, true); // tx succeeded

        assert.equal(await contract.nftContract, '0x123');
        assert.equal((await contract.tokenId).toNumber(), 1);
        assert.equal(await contract.tokenAdded, true);
    });
});
```

Docs:

- Truffle `contract` instead of Mocha `describe` - [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#use-contract-instead-of-describe-)
- The receipt status - Truffle [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function), Web3 [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt) (the link to Web3 in the Truffle docs is outdated)
- Not having to use `.send()` or `.call()` in Truffle, because it choses the tx or call automatically from the contract ABI - [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#calling-getters)

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting `expected [Function] to equal 1` for `assert.equal(await contract.tokenId, 1);`

Comment: @Kevvv Oh it returns a [BigNumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js) instance in JS because it's an `uint256` in Solidity. You can convert the BN to an integer using `(await contract.tokenId).toNumber()`.

Answer (score 1):

I do test this using an ERC721 mock contract in my tests too.
So I deploy both contracts and create new instances for them, then from the ERC721 call the mint function to the contract under test address.
Then check the balance of ERC721 with:

```
ERC721.balanceOf(underTest.address, 1)
```